# Alterar campo select conforme registro sem modificar lista

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Ola,
estou fazendo um formulário para criação/alteração de pedido e tenho uma lista de items via `<select>` onde pega os dados via PHP/MySQL. Quando preencho um numero de pedido existente consigo fazer o valor do select alterar conforme o que esta cadastrado, mas ele esta substituindo o primeiro item da lista.Vejam se me entendem:

**PHP**:

```
<!-- BUSCA PEDIDO-->
<input type="text" name="busca_nro_pedido" id="busca_nro_pedido" placeholder="Pedido..." class="busca_nro_pedido" tabindex="1"/>
<button type="submit" name="btn_buscar_nro_pedido" onclick="carregaDados()">Buscar</button>

// TRANSPORTADORA
$consulta_transp = "SELECT COD, TRANSPORTADORA FROM transp";
$tabela_transp = array();
$resposta_transp = mysqli_query($conexao, $consulta_transp);
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resposta_transp)){
    $tabela_transp += array($linha['COD'] => $linha['TRANSPORTADORA']);
}

<!-- TRANSPORTADORA-->
<label for="transp" class="label_titulos">TRANSPORTADORA</label>
<select name="transp" id="transp" class="busca_nro_pedido select transp">
    <?php foreach($tabela_transp as $chave => $valor){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $chave; ?>" id="transp_txt"><?php echo $valor; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

**JSON**

```
$tabela_transp = array();

if(isset($_SESSION["ped_transp"])){
    $transp_nome = $_SESSION["ped_transp"];
    //$transp_nome = "PLIMOR";
    $consulta_transp = "SELECT t.COD, p.TRANSPORTADORA, t.TRANSPORTADORA FROM transp AS t INNER JOIN pedidos AS p ON t.TRANSPORTADORA = '{$transp_nome}' ORDER BY t.TRANSPORTADORA";
}else{
    $consulta_transp = "SELECT COD, TRANSPORTADORA FROM transp ORDER BY TRANSPORTADORA";
}

$resposta_transp = mysqli_query($conexao, $consulta_transp);
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resposta_transp)){
    $tabela_transp = array($linha['COD'] => $linha['TRANSPORTADORA']);
}

echo json_encode($tabela_transp);
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./pages/listas_transp.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
}).done(function(data){
//console.log(data);
//$("#transp").attr("selected");
$.each(data, function(chave, valor){
    $("#transp_txt").text(valor);
    $("#transp").val(chave);
});
```

Acredito que ele esta fazendo isto por causa do JS que esta atribuindo os valores do select...Como eu faria para alterar o campo select para o mesmo valor que tenho no registro de pedido sem substituir o primeiro valor da lista. Conseguiram me entender?

Comment: Vem no select o valor que o usuário escolheu anteriormente?

Comment: Quando a pagina esta em branco, esta listado os valores do select... quando eu digito o numero do pedido...o select muda para o valor que ta no registro do pedido...mas só que ele ta substituindo o primeiro item que havia no select antes de buscar o pedido.

Comment: Você quer que mantenha os valores e depois incremente com outros?

Comment: Queres que seu código faça o que? Qual o resultado esperado ?

Comment: Eu quero que ele pule para o registro contido no campo select, de acordo com o registro buscado pelo numero do pedido. E não substitua os valores.

Answer (score 0):

Roger, tive que fazer algumas adaptações no código para atender a sua necessidade e ainda assim não tenho certeza. Por que o código está um tanto quanto confuso.

Primeiro: que no seu select os options carregam o mesmo id o que está errado, pois o id deve ser único para cada objeto.

Segundo: no while  do seu "json". Você está fazendo um loop para armazenar o valor em um array pra fazer outro loop no js. Como não faz muito sentido vou simplificar:

```
$html = '';
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resposta_transp)){
    $html .= "<option value='{$linha['COD']}' selected>{$linha['TRANSPORTADORA']}</option>";
}

echo json_encode($html);
```

**Perceba que eu coloquei o *selected* imaginando que só vai vir um valor do banco.**

Se só quer que incremente, substitua a função val() para append()(caso queira por os novos valores no final) ou para prepend(caso queira por no inicio).
Como já estou trazendo os options direto pela variavel data, basta agregar ao select.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./pages/listas_transp.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
}).done(function(data){
   $("#transp").append(data);
});
```

Comment: na verdade, eu nao quero adicionar valores....pois os valores ja estão la..
tipo:
- cada registro de pedido tem um valor de transportadora, esse valor esta listado no select.
- quando eu coloco um numero de pedido no campo de busca, ao carregar, eu preciso que esse valor fique como "selected" no campo select. Sem alterar a lista, apenas pulando para o valor correto.

Comment: Vou fazer um teste aqui, se der certo eu edito a minha resposta.

Comment: Se tiver dúvidas é só perguntar que eu vou editando.